# Hooking GetSysColor in user32.dll

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc, hook

I have a problem hooking the "GetSysColor" function of "user32.dll" in order to modify

```
COLOR_ACTIVECAPTION
COLOR_CAPTIONTEXT
COLOR_INACTIVECAPTION
COLOR_INACTIVECAPTIONTEXT
```

My windows hook class looks like this:

```
CHook(const TCHAR * module, const TCHAR * procname, const void * pNewProc)
{        
    HINSTANCE hMod = GetModuleHandle(module);
    m_pProc = (BYTE*)GetProcAddress(hMod, procname);

    if (m_pProc)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            m_Storage[i] = m_pProc[i];
        }

        DWORD dwOldProtect;
        VirtualProtect(m_pProc, 5, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, & dwOldProtect);
        m_pProc[0] = 0xE9;
        *(unsigned*)(m_pProc + 1) = (unsigned)pNewProc - (unsigned)(m_pProc + 5);
    }
}

~CHook()
{
    if (m_pProc && (m_pProc[0] == 0xE9))
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            m_pProc[i] = m_Storage[i];
        }
    }
}

private:
    BYTE* m_pProc;
    BYTE  m_Storage[5];
```

I wrote a custom getsyscolor method

```
static COLORREF WINAPI GetCustomSysColor(int nIndex)
{
    return RGB(0xFF, 0x00, 0x00);
}
```

to test, if every message gets routed through that function (everything should be red at the end then). I installed it via

```
CHook theHook("user32.dll", "GetSysColor", GetCustomSysColor);
```

Unfortunately, not everything gets painted red, only a few things like icons etc. But the colors mentioned at the beginning are the former system settings - captions are still drawn blue with white text. I even debugged it and the colors for caption arrive in the GetCustomSysColors method.

Maybe anybody knows if there is another winapi call going on for the caption or if I missed anything important. Thank you very much!

Cheers,
Chris

Comment: This is not how you customize your caption. The way to customize your caption is by handling the WM_NCPAINT message.

Comment: No. For my application, hooking is the best solution. OnNcPaint() with a) changing systemcolors or b) painting your own caption is too slow and cumbersome.

Comment: No. Raymond is correct. There are lots of problems with your proposed solution. It really shouldn't be any faster if you've written the code correctly that runs when a WM_NCPAINT message is received, but even if this is faster, it's not going to work correctly. For starters, the system heavily caches the brushes for system colors; it doesn't need to recreate them each time they're needed by calling the GetSysColor function.. What are you going to do about those?

Comment: The system doesn't call GetSysColor to get the colors. It already knows what the colors are. (Anif visual styles are enabled, then the caption isn't even a color.)

Comment: Thanks for the hint with the system brushes. I will investigate this further later.

Answer (score 2):

1) thought, you forgot [GetSysColorBrush](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd144927%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

2) on the other side, there are other system libraries, which may be used by gdi, you may try to use debugger breakpoints to identify them

3) as about caption, it may be painted by `DrawCaption`, `GradientFill`, or with theming functions (XP or higher) like `DrawThemeBackground`.